# How can I find out if effects vary by race if I am including family-level fixed effects?

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model

I don't have a working example, because this question is more conceptual.  Let's say I'm running a linear regression using the `plm` package in R on the relationship between graduating from college and getting lunch-subsidies as a child.

I have panel data that includes observations from individuals that may be in the same family, so I add family-level fixed effects to allow for arbitrary correlations within the family.

If I were to add race covariates, however, R would omit them because of multicollinearity in the family level.

How would I test the hypothesis, then, that blacks have differential effects than whites, but still resolving the issues solved by fixed effects?

**To answer the questions below:**

Let's say I have the following regression, attempting to test for the hypothesis that different races and sexes are helped differentially from a free lunch program insofar as it relates to graduating college:

```
plm(graduate_college ~ free_lunch + black + male + hispanic + data=data, index=c("mother_id"), model="within")
```

Mother_ID just tracks siblings from the same mother.  Now, if I want to test the hypothesis that blacks have different effects than whites as it relates to the effect of free lunch on graduating college, how would I test this?  My guess is to remove fixed effects, add clustered standard errors at the mother_id level and add an interaction term for black*free_lunch?

Comment: Can you show your model in standard mixed effects notation? The family level fixed effect seems odd to me. Let's say you have 100,000 observations. If you have 3 people in family in average, then it's 30,000 fixed effects. This sounds a little bit crazy, unless I;m missing something

Comment: Just to be clear, you're *nesting* individuals within families, correct? Also, you've tried fitting race into your model as a main effect? R returns it as a linear combination (collinear) with the "family" level? That doesn't make sense to me if it's a simple main effect. It would make more sense to me if you were to take the interaction of race and lunch subsidies.

Comment: Also, what's your hypothesis? That somehow some races are not being helped by free lunches? I'm just curious

Comment: I tried to answer these questions, @Aksakal To be clear: I'm just learning this stuff.

Comment: Let's say you make this regression work, what would this mean though? Are you trying to see whether subsidized lunch help higher education? Would it say that it's not income that's preventing some races getting higher education? It's not clear what's the research question here,

Comment: I am arguing that subsidized lunch increases the probability of higher education but has differential effects on black vs. whites.

Comment: Given the edits to your question, why not treat race as a single categorical variable rather than breaking each race out separately? This would simplify the test of the differential effects between race and subsidized lunches. Next and to @aksakal 's point, free lunch is a dummy variable conflating many, many related factors having to do with income, SES, geography (as in zip codes), etc. In educational research, it's viewed more as a statement of a *lack* of access or barrier to higher education. In other words, it's not an unambiguous test as there are many confounding, unobserved effects.

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you're interested in causal relationship, i.e. lunch helps education. I'm not sure that this kind of regression can support the causal statements. For instance, I could say that both lack of higher education and the fact that a kid asked for free lunch could be **results** of poor background. Consider this: in USA when people buy houses they look at neighboring school statistics. High ratio of subsidized meal children -> assume neighborhood is poor -> expect low house prices -> town's property tax revenue is low -> less money to schools -> worse teahcers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as you mentioned above: "Remove fixed effects, add clustered standard errors at the mother_id level and add an interaction term for black*free_lunch."  There's really no need for family-level fixed effects if all you're trying to do is control for intra-cluster correlation within families.  Clustering your standard errors will make the appropriate adjustments for intra-cluster correlation.

Comment: What are the circumstances in which you'd want to add both family-level fixed effects and clustered standard errors at the family-level?